# Why can't we get the thread termination code from the detached thread?

Tags: pthreads, posix

My question is strange, but that's what it is. My question: Is there any explanation why the posix threads developers did not make it possible to get the exit code from a detached thread?

I understand what an joinable thread is and a detached thread, and how they differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why the posix threads developers did not make it possible to get the exit code from a detached thread

Because they can't know *when* you might ask for this exit code.

In order to provide the exit code for a detached thread, that info must be kept *somewhere*, consuming storage. Since there is no point where it would be possible to say "we don't need this storage anymore" (since you could ask for this exit code at any point in the future), that storage would have to exist forever.

If your application creates and destroys detached threads in a loop, this would result in the POSIX thread library consuming more and more space, which would look like a memory leak.

Contrast this with a non-detached thread, where the storage is kept until you call `pthread_join()`, after which point any storage can be safely re-used.